# jQuery saving data and loading every refresh page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hey im really newbie of walking around in js, saw a nice code about to-do list and would like to save it in every refresh page (in local storage). Have tried savy.js plugin but it doesn't really work. Was thinking about making some json file but don't really know how it would work in jQuery. here is my code:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="list">
  <input type="text" class="txtb" placeholder="Add a task">
  <div class="notcomp">
    <h3>Not Completed</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="comp">
    <h3>Completed</h3>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".txtb").on("keyup", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13 && $(".txtb").val() != "") {
      var task = $("<div class='task'></div>").text($(".txtb").val());
      var del = $("<i class='fas fa-trash-alt'></i>").click(function() {
        var p = $(this).parent();
        p.fadeOut(function() {
          p.remove();
        })
      });
      var check = $("<i class='fas fa-check'></i>").click(function() {
        var p = $(this).parent();
        p.fadeOut(function() {
          $(".comp").append(p);
          p.fadeIn();
        });
        $(this).remove();
      });
      task.append(del, check);
      $(".notcomp").append(task);
      $(".txtb").val("");
    }
  });
</script>
```

Aprieciate for any help.

Comment: clarify your requirement.

Comment: You have to use Browser storage like Localstorage, sessionstorage or Cookies.

Answer (score 0):

try this code or check the example at [Task List](https://codepen.io/libin-prasanth/pen/zYYLZLr)

**HTML**

```
<div class="list">
  <input type="text" class="txtb" placeholder="Add a task">
  <div class="notcomp">
    <h3>Not Completed</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="comp">
    <h3>Completed</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var data = localStorage.getItem("todo");
  if (data != "" && data != null) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
      insertTask(value);
    }
  } else {
    data = [];
  }

  function insertTask(data) {
    var task = $("<div class='task'></div>").text(data.value);
    var del = $("<i class='fa fa-trash' ></i>").click(function() {
      removeData(data.id);
      $(this)
        .parent(".task")
        .fadeOut("slow", function() {
          $(this).remove();
        });
    });

    task.append(del);
    $(".notcomp").append(task);
  }

  function removeData(id) {
    console.log(id);
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
      if (value.id === id) {
        data.splice(key, 1);
        localStorage.setItem("todo", JSON.stringify(data));
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  $(".txtb").on("keyup", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13 && $(".txtb").val() != "") {
      let val = $(".txtb").val();

      var unix = Math.round(+new Date() / 1000);
      var taskData = {
        value: val,
        id: unix
      };
      data.push(taskData);
      insertTask(taskData);
      localStorage.setItem("todo", JSON.stringify(data));
      $(".txtb").val("");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Hey, It's working and saving to local storage. Updated it with checkbox : [link](http://wklejto.pl/txt780805). After add something to ".comp" div and refreshing page everything goes to "not.comp" div How can i change a key value ? Was looking whole day about some information about local storage.Thanks for help:)